# How to make new event handler in user control with event action from form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm Working on a game that uses multiple layouts. To make those layouts, I use user controls by bringing them forward and sending them behind. I figured out a way to send info between user control and form, but I'm stuck with making new event handler in my user control with info from my form. I'm trying to send event action from form to my user control, but User control gives `non-static field, method or property` error. It worked with sending info from user control to form so I'm looking for a help with fixing that and also understand why it won't work this way I did it

My Form part of code

```
        public event EventHandler Start;
    public void kumme(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uCmehanism1.BringToFront();
        int Between = 1;
        if (this.Start != null)
            this.Start(this, e);
    }
```

My 'UCmehanism' part of code

```
        public UCmehanism()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form.Start += new EventHandler(alusta); /*form.start gives me the error, everything else is good*/
    }
    public void alusta(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: You need to create an instance of your form and access the event on the instance (i.e. it is not static).

Answer (score 0):

First the Disclaimer: Windows Forms is not the right way to go about game development. For simple Turnbased games that are singleplayer or maybe hotseat multiplayer it can work. If you do not go to far for Animations. Consider the Old Windows Solitaire to be on the top end of "what is possible" in Windows Forms.

There are dedicated ways to go about game development. Mostly those are XNA and whatever from this list you can get to work agaisnt your target framework of choice: https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/apps/gaming. But anything with a implementation of a game loop works. Consider that as more of a longterm information.

Your error is specifically a Compiler error. The Compiler is complaining that it does not understand what you want. Unfortunately when this particular error happens (non-static field, method or property) stuff is harder to debug. Most of the times it means that something **way** before the point of marked error went wrong. Some closing bracket is missing or a Semicolon to much/where it does not belong. It is tripping up so badly, it can not even tell what alusa is supposed to be. Or even what is supposed to be at that place.

Comment: I'm making mathematical equation game with minimal animations.
as the compiling part, other code doesn't gimme any errors, only that so I don't think is about brackets or semicolons. From your perspective, do you think it's more problematic in user control getting info or form sending it? I'm a beginner, so not too experienced with good and functional code writing

Comment: @KarlisSaarna: "non-static field, method or property" is a Compiler/Code Parsing Error. There is nothing else it could be. It is clearly a CS class of error (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120). So it has nothing to do with the User Control. And everything with your general code.